# How do I save complex data in firebase from android studio?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

route is single data set. Route contains String values an array lists. I want to save it in firebase database. How can I do it?

This is how my database looks like:
[image: database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Map and set all your data, then just send it to your database

Example

```
 Map<String, Object> routeUp = new HashMap<>();
        routeUp.put("description", "EXAMPLE");
        routeUp.put("haultName", "NAME");
        routeUp.put("latitude","idontknowwhyyoustoreitwithastring");
        //... and so on
        mDatabase.child("route").child(routeUp).updateChildren(routeUp).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error saving the values " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

you can then merge more than one `HashMap` and use `putAll` to finally send all the structure in one click

Example

```
map3 = new HashMap<>();
//...
map3.putAll(map1);
map3.putAll(map2);
```

Then just push only the Map containing all the structure

Note: be aware that sending so many data like this could cause more than one NPE (NullPointerException) if one or more values are empty, you should handle some kind of exception,